# Django: View-function fails on saving model

Tags: django, django-models

I'm currently playing around with some selfmade online Text-RPG and now have to deal with some quite strange problem which I hope someone here can solve.

I'd like to toggle a boolean field called 'rp_willing' in the model 'Character' when clicking on certain links. For that I have a view function called 'character_toggle_rp_willing'.

The field definition:

```
class Character(models.Model):
    ...
    rp_willing = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ...
```

The view function:

```
@decorators.login_required
def character_toggle_rp_willing(request, id):
    character = get_object_or_404(Character, pk=id)
    character.rp_willing = not character.rp_willing
    character.save()
    return redirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER','/accounts/overview'))
```

It queries the character in question from the database by it's id. Then 'rp_willing' is toggled and the character is saved before the function redirects back to the previous page.

The problem now seems to lie in the call of 'character.save()'. I've placed some print-functions for debugging purposes and everything else seems to work as intended. Also, the whole functions works absolutly correct if called from a template of the same app. But if the template is from a differente app, the save-function just isn't executed. There is no exception which could give any hints. I don't really know, how to debug in this case. I couldn't find the code of the built-in save()-function either.

Is the save()-function somehow related to the passed request? Or is there something I have just overlooked?

EDIT:
What the Dev-Server says...

Works as intended:

```
[28/Aug/2011 17:06:53] "GET /accounts/overview HTTP/1.1" 200 2283                                                        
[28/Aug/2011 17:06:59] "GET /accounts/character/toggle_rp_willing/1/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[28/Aug/2011 17:06:59] "GET /accounts/overview HTTP/1.1" 200 2285
```

Fails on saving:

```
[28/Aug/2011 17:03:26] "GET /village/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1531                                                                 
[28/Aug/2011 17:03:28] "GET /accounts/character/toggle_rp_willing/1/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[28/Aug/2011 17:03:28] "GET /village/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1531
```

Comment: With the two examples you give right at the end, we need to be able to see the preceding step (ie. the line before `/toggle_rp_willing/`, to see what the referring page is.

Comment: I added them now. But in my mind these lines show only that everything is working correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, turned out I was just looking from a wrong angle. The problem is not my 'character_toggle_rp_willing' for it saves the character as it should. But the view it redirects to does not retrieve the character-data from the database. Instead it uses the data stored in a session variable - the old data. And then there is a method called, that saves that old data, so nothing changes in the end... I guess I should look for a good debugger.